# Replacing zeros with mean of each customer

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I want to write a function that replace all zeros with the mean of each customer category.

for example (before):

[image]

After:

[image]

I tried the below code:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"customer_number":[1,2,3,2,3,1,2,1],"A":[12, 4, 5, 0, 1,2,0,1],
                   "B":[0, 2, 54, 3, 0,4,1,0],
                   "C":[20, 16, 0, 3, 8,5,8,10],
                   "D":[14, 3, 0, 0, 6,7,15,0], 
                   "E":[8, 0, 4, 0, 0,8,2,3],
                   "F":[20, 80, 0, 15, 0,7,5,0],
                   "G":[7, 0, 3, 0, 1,9,0,6],
                   "H":[25, 13,0, 0, 5,4,0,7]})
df 

df.replace(0,df.mean(axis=0),inplace=True)
df
```

This gives the mean for the entire column with no conditional of customer category.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) for means per groups and replace missing values by [`DataFrame.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
df = df.mask(df.eq(0), df.groupby('customer_number').transform('mean'))
    
print (df)
   customer_number          A          B   C   D         E   F  G          H
0                1  12.000000   1.333333  20  14  8.000000  20  7  25.000000
1                2   4.000000   2.000000  16   3  0.666667  80  0  13.000000
2                3   5.000000  54.000000   4   3  4.000000   0  3   2.500000
3                2   1.333333   3.000000   3   6  0.666667  15  0   4.333333
4                3   1.000000  27.000000   8   6  2.000000   0  1   5.000000
5                1   2.000000   4.000000   5   7  8.000000   7  9   4.000000
6                2   1.333333   1.000000   8  15  2.000000   5  0   4.333333
7                1   1.000000   1.333333  10   7  3.000000   9  6   7.000000
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
df2 = df.mask(df.eq(0))

df2.combine_first(df
 .groupby('customer_number')
 .mean()
 .reindex(df['customer_number'])
 .reset_index()
 )
```

Output:

```
   customer_number          A          B     C     D         E     F    G          H
0                1  12.000000   1.333333  20.0  14.0  8.000000  20.0  7.0  25.000000
1                2   4.000000   2.000000  16.0   3.0  0.666667  80.0  0.0  13.000000
2                3   5.000000  54.000000   4.0   3.0  4.000000   0.0  3.0   2.500000
3                2   1.333333   3.000000   3.0   6.0  0.666667  15.0  0.0   4.333333
4                3   1.000000  27.000000   8.0   6.0  2.000000   0.0  1.0   5.000000
5                1   2.000000   4.000000   5.0   7.0  8.000000   7.0  9.0   4.000000
6                2   1.333333   1.000000   8.0  15.0  2.000000   5.0  0.0   4.333333
7                1   1.000000   1.333333  10.0   7.0  3.000000   9.0  6.0   7.000000
```

Comment: this does not give my required answers, I need for each customer number replace his zeros with category mean.

Comment: @Ahmed if you want to include the zeros in the mean calculation, just use df as source instead of df2 (see update)

Answer (score 0):

This code does it for me.

```js
df = df.astype('float')      # converting the dataframe to float
for i in df.columns[1:]:     # looping over the columns
    mean = df.groupby(['customer_number'])[i].mean()     # saving the mean of each category for each column
    for index,element in enumerate(df[i]): # iterating over the individual column
        if element == 0: # replacing only the observations that are 0 
            cust_numb = df.customer_number[index] # getting the mean of the corresponding category
            df[i][index] = mean[cust_numb] # replacing the observation
```

Comment: @AhmedEwis - Performance is not important?

Comment: @jezrael 
I was thinking the same thing.
Even I am relatively new to python and coding. 
is there a way to measure the performance of these approaches?

Comment: @SamuelThudi - check `timeit` function in spyder

Comment: I ran %%timeit for the 3 answers that are working.
lets call them J M & S for the 3 authors. 
Results are as below:
 
J = 8.91 ms ± 312 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


S = 12.7 ms ± 2.16 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)


M = 20.9 ms ± 621 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

Comment: It took a lot time but I categorized my data to different groups

Comment: @jezrael I did not see your answer, it works perfectly and much way faster!!